# A small simulation study about normality tests in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am conducting a small simulation study to judge how good two normality tests really are. My plan is to generate a multitude of normal distribution samples of not too many observations and determine how often each test rejects the null hypothesis of normality.

The (incomplete) code I have so far is

```
  library(nortest)
  y<-replicate(10000,{
     x<-rnorm(50)
     ad.test(x)$p.value
     ks.test(x,y=pnorm)$p.value
   }
   )
```

Now I would like to count the proportion of these p-values that are smaller than 0.05 for each test. Could you please tell me how I could do that? I apologise if this is a newbie question, but I myself am new to R.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 library(nortest)
 nsim <- 10000
 nx <- 50

 set.seed(101)
 y <- replicate(nsim,{
    x<-rnorm(nx)
    c(ad=ad.test(x)$p.value,
      ks=ks.test(x,y=pnorm)$p.value)
  }
 )
 apply(y<0.05,MARGIN=1,mean)
 ##     ad     ks 
 ## 0.0534 0.0480
```

Using `MARGIN=1` tells `apply` to take the mean across rows, rather than columns -- this is sensible given the ordering that `replicate()`'s built-in simplification produces.

For examples of this type, the type I error rates of any standard tests will be *extremely* close to their nominal value (0.05 in this example).

Comment: PS you could speed this up a bit by picking all the Normal values at once and putting them in a matrix ...

Comment: Thanks, that does it. If I may ask though, why did you put 1 as second argument in the apply function?

Answer (score 2):

If you run each test separately, then you can simply count which vals are stored in y that are less than 0.05.

```
y<-replicate(1000,{
     x<-rnorm(50)
     ks.test(x,y=pnorm)$p.value})
length(which(y<0.05))
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like each test to be on the same sample.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't outputting the p-values.  You could do something like this:

```
rep_test <- function(reps=10000) {

  p_ks <- rep(NA, reps)
  p_ad <- rep(NA, reps)

  for (i in 1:reps) {
    x <- rnorm(50)
    p_ks[i] <- ks.test(x, y=pnorm)$p.value
    p_ad[i] <- ad.test(x)$p.value
  }

  return(data.frame(cbind(p_ks, p_ad)))
}

sum(test$p_ks<.05)/10000
sum(test$p_ad<.05)/10000
```